# Find the max sum for each line and find max list and line number of maximum list count in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
"[1.0, 0.5]","[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]","[0.5, 0.5]"

"[1.0, 0.0]","[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]","[0.0, 0.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]","[0.0, 0.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]","[1.0, 1.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]","[0.5, 0.5]"
```

"[1.0, 0.5]","[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]","[0.5, 0.5]"

```
"[1.0, 0.0]","[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]","[0.0, 0.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]","[0.0, 0.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]","[1.0, 1.0]"

"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]","[0.5, 0.5]"
```

I have list of diagonals now i want to find the sum for each list in each line. Output should be like this

```
1.5

1.5

0

3

1.5

1
```

How can i do this?

Comment: are they lines or lists?

Comment: In each line there are lists

Comment: so they are string representations of lists? Also how is the max 3 for the third line?

Comment: what do you mean by string representations?

Comment: I mean you are using list and line interchangeably, what do you have strings or lists? Are these lines of a file?

Comment: No no sorry my mistake i edit 3rd line

Comment: Yes these are lines of file

Comment: And that is exactly how they look?

Comment: Yes thats exactly they look

Answer (score 2):

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.csv") as f:
    for ind, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if line.strip():  # catch empty lines
            print(ind,max(sum(literal_eval(sub.strip('"'))) for sub in line.rstrip().split('",')))
```

Output:

```
(1, 1.5)
(2, 1.5)
(3, 0.0)
(4, 3.0)
(5, 2.0)
(6, 1.0)
```

Using the csv module makes life easier as it does the splitting correctly for us:

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for ind, row in enumerate(reader,1):
        if row: # only needed if you have empty rows
            print(ind, max(sum(literal_eval(sub)) for sub in row))
```

Output:

```
(1, 1.5)
(2, 1.5)
(3, 0.0)
(4, 3.0)
(5, 2.0)
(6, 1.0)
```

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Considering you have a csv file then it is a no brainer which option to use.

If you want the max of all the lines, we can use a generator expression to get the max from each line then use operator.itemgetter to get the max based on the second element of our tuple which is the max:

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval
from operator import itemgetter
with open("in.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    totals = ((ind, max(sum(literal_eval(sub))for sub in row))
              for ind, row in enumerate(reader, 1) if row)
    print(max(totals,key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Output:

```
 (4, 3.0) # line 4
```

Comment: How to find the max when there are chunks of lines separated by blank line

Comment: @abd, I don't understand what you mean, the code ignores empty lines.

Comment: Thanks @padraic cunningham

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine i want to ask that if there are more than one inputs in this file separated by balnk line then how to find the max upto a blank line?

Comment: You mean stop on the first empty line?

Comment: Yes and then again start from next nonempty line and find max upto next blank line

Comment: You would need to break on finding an empty line and get the max of all you have collected so far, then reset the container or max value and continue on again

Comment: k i will try to do this

Comment: I break this where blank line came but i am unable to find the max from the collected numbers

Answer (score 0):

The sum in your second line from the bottom should be 2. Just threw together a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if not line.strip(): continue
    print max([sum(eval(l)) for l in line.strip('\n"').split('","')])
```

Comment: I have a csv file which contains the above lines of lists

Comment: I copied and pasted the input from your question verbatim. If that's not actually how your input file looks, you should edit your question so the example input reflects the actual input.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(max(sum(eval(string)) for string in eval(line)))
```

Or if your file and output really have those empty lines:

```
with open('test.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            print(max(sum(eval(string)) for string in eval(line)))
        else:
            print()
```